# Как обновить сообщение через Bot.EditMessageTextAsync()

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Как изменить сообщение размещенное над `InlineKeyboardButton`? Хочу чтобы после нажатия на кнопку `Refresh` текст сообщения изменялся на `$"Message Was Created: {DateTime.Now}"`

```
private static async void BotOnMessageReceived(object sender, 
                                            MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
    {
        var message = messageEventArgs.Message;
        if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.TextMessage) return;
        await Bot.SendChatActionAsync(message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);
                var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup("Refresh")
                 );
        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    message.Chat.Id,
                    $"Message Was Created: {DateTime.Now}",
                    replyMarkup: keyboard);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
private static async void BotOnCallbackQueryReceived(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs callbackQueryEventArgs)
    {
       var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("Refresh"));
        await Bot.EditMessageTextAsync( 
            callbackQueryEventArgs.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, 
            callbackQueryEventArgs.CallbackQuery.Message.MessageId, 
            $"Data Was Edited at {DateTime.Now}",
            replyMarkup: keyboard);

        await Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(
            callbackQueryEventArgs.CallbackQuery.Id,
            $"Data Was Updated");
    }
```

Новый текст сообщения должен отличатся от предыдущего или придется обрабатывать

> Bad Request: message is not modified.